# SpriteKit alpha mask not working on iOS 13.4

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I am having a problem with SpriteKit, where Alpha mask option for an element completely destroys the game (it just shows Scene with background). If I change that element back to body type: Bounding rectangle, then all elements are shown in the scene.

**Working option**

[image: Bounding rectangle]

**Not working option**

[image: Alpha mask]

Any solution for this?

Comment: it hasn't been working since ios 13 started, and it doesn't look like Apple gives a crap about it

Comment: @RonMyschuk Is there anything that I can do to go around it? Do you know how can I make the Alpha mask programatically? Also, what if I would like to add Alpha mask for a wave or something in that shape? I am new to SpriteKit

Comment: in the past, I've done 2 things. evaluate how badly I need that exactness. If not very badly I just use a generic shape (square, circle) . If I do need an exactness I use a program called PaintCode to create vector points to create a path. I then load that path in my class and apply a physics body from the path. Pain in the butt, but that was the only way I found around it

Comment: @RonMyschuk Thanks! Do you use Bezierpath to generate vector points?

Comment: PaintCode does that for me, it outputs the code and everything (as Bezier paths)